# Why are so many recreational drugs serotonin 5-HT1A partial agonists?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neurotransmitter, psychoneuropharmacology, serotonin

I found out that many psychoactive drugs partially activate the 5HT<sub>1</sub>A receptor. Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-HT1A_receptor#Partial_agonists), these include MDMA, LSD, CBD, Psliocybin/Psilocin, amphetamine and various other psychedelics, and they appear to all be serotonin 5-HT<sub>1</sub>A partial agonists.

Why is this receptor so popular for recreational drugs? Why are all these *partial* instead of full agonists? I looked at 5-HT<sub>1</sub>B and there weren't any recreational drugs that used this listed. [I looked at other 5-HT receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-HT_receptor#Subtypes), and only 5-HT<sub>2</sub>A had other recreational drugs as agonists.

Why do so many recreational drugs affect these two 5-HT receptors?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to edit your question, mainly to remove any pointer to possible self-help content. This site explicitly bans self-help questions as we are not in a position to provide information on personal health issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting notion. However, the main effects of the indoleamine-class of psychoactive compounds, including [psilocybin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psilocybin) and [LSD](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/scicurious-brain/httpblogsscientificamericancomscicurious-brain20110802sciam-chemistry-day-lsd-a-drug-only-as-good-as-its-receptors/) [(Shulgin, 1997)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0963009699), are generally ascribed to 5-HT<sub>2</sub>A receptors and the glutamatergic system [(Aghajanian & Marek, 1999)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10432484). The stimulant effects of the phenetylamines (PEAs) such as amphetamine and related compounds [(Shulgin, 1991)](http://www.shulginresearch.org/home/publications/pihkal/) mainly target the [dopamine](http://www.news-medical.net/health/Dopamine-Functions.aspx) (DA) and [noradrenergic](http://www.els.net/WileyCDA/ElsArticle/refId-a0001401.html) (NE) systems. I reckon that the 5HT<sub>1</sub>A effects are 'side effects', or secondary effects.

Antidepressants, such as the [selective serotonin-reuptake inhibitors](http://www.webmd.com/depression/ssris-myths-and-facts-about-antidepressants),  target the 5HT<sub>1</sub>A system and mainly do so by downregulating the pre-synaptic variant of the 5HT<sub>1</sub>A receptors, which have a regulatory role by decreasing 5HT release. Downregulating them takes about 2 weeks. After that time 5HT release is disinhibited and 5HT release is enhanced, which has antidepressant actions (source: [*Sci Am*, 2013](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/scicurious-brain/knocking-5-ht1a-down-to-bring-mood-up/)). Because many recreational drugs are not taken that long, my educated guess is that acute activation of 5HT<sub>1</sub>A by recreational drugs limits the drug's effect more than anything else.

Why are they partial agonists? Because they target other receptors better; the main effects of *e.g.*, PEAs as described above shows you why. Many of those compounds mainly target the DA and NE system. Because they are aspecific ('dirty') drugs, they also target a variety of other receptor systems. Perhaps altering the main effect, perhaps not doing anything substantial to the trip.

Note that the PEA MDMA is kind of a one-of-a-kind psychoactive compound [(Shulgin, 1991)](http://www.shulginresearch.org/home/publications/pihkal/) that releases massive amounts of 5HT [(Gartside *et al*., 1997)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9517441).

<sub>On a side note, Wikipedia tends to list all available information on an item in a cluttered way that obscures the relevance of that information to the global picture.</sub>

<sub>**References**

**-** [Aghajanian & Marek, *Neuropsychopharmacology* (1999); **21**(2 Suppl): 16S-23S](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10432484)

**-** [Gartside *et al*., *Neuropharmacology* (1997); **36**(11-12): 1697-703](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9517441)

**-** [Shulgin, Pihkal (1991), Transform Press](http://www.shulginresearch.org/home/publications/pihkal/)

**-** [Shulgin, Tihkal (1997), Transform Press](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0963009699)</sub>

Comment: +1 I too have heard that antipsychotics that primarily target DAR can also affect 5HTR